# Joi validation when either of two values are present or missing

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

Have three parameters: `latitude, longitude, zipcode`

I need a [joi validation](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) that

- requires latitude AND longitude when either is present OR zipcode is missing
- requires zipcode when EITHER latitude or longitude is missing.

Something like this?

```
Joi.object().keys({
    latitude: Joi.number().when('zipcode', { is: undefined, then: Joi.required() }),
    longitude: Joi.number().when('zipcode', { is: undefined, then: Joi.required() }),
    zipcode: Joi.number().when(['latitude', 'longitude'], { is: undefined, then: Joi.required() })
});
```

I'm thinking there is a more elegant solution maybe using [object.and()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.2.0/API.md#objectandpeers)

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Nope. I used a hack which somewhat serves my purpose in that it won't allow values I don't want but the error messages are confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can validate multiple conditions in the following schema.

> ```
>     const schema = Joi.object().keys({
>         searchby: Joi.string().valid('phone', '_id', 'cno').required(), // field name
>         searchvalue: Joi
>             .when('searchby', { is: "phone", then: Joi.string().regex(/^(923)\d{9}$/, 'numbers').max(12).min(12).required() })
>             .when('searchby', { is: "_id", then: Joi.objectId().required() })
>             .when('searchby', { is: "nic", then: Joi.number().required() })
>     });
> ```

Comment: It would be more useful if this snippet was adapted to the inputs in the original question, but this is a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

This solution may be useful:

```js
schema = Joi.object().keys({
  location: Joi.object().keys({
    lat: Joi.number(),
    long: Joi.number()
  }).and('lat', 'long'),
  timezone: Joi.alternatives()
    .when('location', {
        is: null,
        then: Joi.number().required(),
        otherwise: Joi.number()
    })
});
```

Comment: That solution only works if you change the structure of the data though.